# How to add zero in front of a variable in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, variables, comparison, leading-zero

I need to add a zero in front of a variable, but I need to compare two variables before making it. After that, another treatment will reduce the number of digits in each variable, but first I need them to be intact. Why? because in my actual Batch File, my latest version won't being installed because it sees the latest version like if it was older than the installed one and it is false.

It happens because the reduction only keep the first 5 digits of each variable. In this problem, the variable of the installed version became greater than the newest version and of course I don't want this, that is why I want to add a zero in front of the installed one but only if the number of digit are not the same like in this case.

In my treatment, I extract the installed version number and place it into a variable and also for the newest version then I remove the dots in both and I reduce the numbers of digit to 5 or else when it comes to compare it won't work if the variable are too long. So I had this idea below to adjust the number of digit in both variable before the reducing but this part doesn't work.

**Original Version before treatment : Installed_Version = 98.0.4758.82 and Version = 100.0.4896.88

```
set /A Trimmed_Installed_Version = 980475882
set /A Trimmed_Version = 1000489688
set /A Niveau = 1
set Compare = %Trimmed_Version% / %Trimmed_Installed_Version%
if "%Compare%" GTR "%Niveau%"
    (
    do set Trimmed_Installed_Version = 0%Trimmed_Installed_Version%
    )
echo %Trimmed_Installed_Version%
```

As you can see, the first two variables are what I have at this point in my treatment after an echo, I just reported it to this part's code. Any idea how to make this work or else I'm open to a better idea?

Comment: As nobody has mentioned it, your first three lines are technically incorrect, they should read as `Set "Trimmed_Installed_Version=980475882"`, `Set "Trimmed_Version=1000489688"`, and `Set "Niveau=1"`. Your fourth line is incorrect, and does not use the documented syntax, which should read as `Set /A Compare = Trimmed_Version / Trimmed_Installed_Version`. I will also. say that your methodology should probably be modified too, split the version using the known period, and make your comparisons of each sequence between those, first to last as needed, after all 98 will always be LSS 100, etc.

Comment: Could you explain me how to split the version number from the period in it, please? I find out that it could be a good idea, but I'm between beginner and advance at this and unfortunately for me nobody except internet could help me to find some answer?

Comment: Or maybe if there a way to flush the last digits, unstead of keeping the first digits, it will make it too, but once again I don't know how...

Answer (score 0):

Calculating `%Trimmed_Version% / %Trimmed_Installed_Version%` is fine in theory. Problem is that batch is integer-only, so the value assigned is int(%Trimmed_Version% / %Trimmed_Installed_Version%) or `1`. Which is not greater than 1. Hence the `if` is not true.

There's no reason that you can't use

```
if %Trimmed_Version% GTR %Trimmed_Installed_Version% (
```

since both values are <2**32.

Note that if you prefix the string with `0` as you appear intending on, then the value is no longer a valid batch integer, as a leading `0` means that the number is **octal** and hence must be all-digits and cannot contain `8` or `9`.

**But** by prefixing with a `0` to make the values the same *length* (all batch variables are **strings** and may be used as integers if they are (signed) numeric-only) then they can be compared with `if "%one%" op "%theother%" (`

Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"

Use `set "var1=value"` for setting **STRING** values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Quotes are not needed for setting arithmetic values `(`set /a`)

It may be worth noting for your purposes that the third element in eg.,
`98.0.4758.82` so far has been ever-increasing in Google versions, so perhaps comparing that alone may suffice. The same may not apply to other vendors.

Comment: Is there a way to clear all digits following the second dot in each version? Effectively I need to adjust this not only for Google Chrome but for a GPO_Template

Comment: `for /f "tokens=3delims=." %%v in ("%versionstringincludingdots%") do set "magic=%%v"` should extract that information. see `for /f` from the prompt and numerous SO items for how this works.